# TypeError no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, typeerror

I'm trying to add social sharing to a Rails project, but I keep getting this `no implicit conversion of nil into String` on both lines below:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= CGI::escape(root_url) %>?ref=<%= CGI::escape(@user.referral_code) %>&title=wdyw" class="fb" target="_blank"></a>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<%= CGI::escape(root_url) %>?ref=<%= CGI::escape(@user.referral_code) %>&text=<%= CGI::escape(twitter_message) %>" class="twit" target="_blank"></a>
```

I'm on ruby version 2.6. Not sure what the error is.

Comment: Am guessing your `@user` doesn't have a referral code. You'll get the same error if you do `CGI::escape(nil)`.

Comment: `CGI::escape(stuff_that_can_be_nil || '')` if you just want to ignore it, or surround the link with `<% if stuff_that_can_be_nil %>` if you want to hide or replace the link in case `stuff_that_can_be_nil` is `nil`.

Comment: You're correct @dinjas. the referral code was missing. Thanks